# VBA code for unhiding a bookmarked text is not working

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've created an ActiveX dropdown list and each option is linked to a bookmark for the text. Under the ActiveX controls there are the bookmarks (`R1` and`R2`), hidden.

When I hit the `btnselect` button, all the other bookmarks, except the selected one, get deleted and the selected one becomes visible.
In the bookmark `R2`

I have a `MacroButton` for showing/hiding another text (`CollapseMentiuniReclamant`). When clicking the button it runs either `Expand1` sub or `Collapse1` sub, but the bookmark `CollapseMentiuniReclamant` doesn't show up.

I've simplified the document and codes as much as possible. Link to the document - https://wetransfer.com/downloads/1caea3c5d3b05e226e8b8f6a29760ad220190522071742/15db59.

The vba code is:

```
Private Sub btnselect_Click()
If ComboBox1.Value = "1" Then
Bookmarks("R1").Range.Font.Hidden = False
Bookmarks("R2").Range.Font.Hidden = False
Bookmarks("R2").Range.Delete
End If
If ComboBox1.Value = "2" Then
Bookmarks("R1").Range.Font.Hidden = False
Bookmarks("R1").Range.Delete
Bookmarks("R2").Range.Font.Hidden = False
Bookmarks("CollapseMentiuniReclamant").Range.Font.Hidden = True
End If
End Sub
Sub Expand1()
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("Collapse1").Insert _
Where:=Selection.Range
Bookmarks("CollapseMentiuniReclamant").Range.Font.Hidden = False
End Sub
Sub Collapse1()
ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate.BuildingBlockEntries("Expand1").Insert _
Where:=Selection.Range
Bookmarks("CollapseMentiuniReclamant").Range.Font.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

Update: I've simplified the last part of code and the problem still persists:

```
Sub Expand1()
Bookmarks("CollapseMentiuniReclamant").Range.Font.Hidden = False
End Sub
```

I've even removed the button entirely and ran the macro from View Macros Tab and it's not working.
Why doesn't `CollapseMentiuniReclamant` show up?

Comment: On Stack Overflow, all information relevant to a problem needs to be *in the question* - links to outside sources should not be necessary. This is a Q&A site and its content should be helpful to others, not just the original person with the problem. It's not possible to understand this problem understanding how the document is built - we need to be able to reproduce it. Please provide a [mcve] entirely within the question that contains just the information necessary to reproduce the issue, along with an exact description of how the code currently works and what the expected/desired result is.

Answer (score 0):

It's not showing up because what you're trying to hide/unhide isn't inside the bookmarked range. In any event, you should be inserting/deleting the content, not simply toggling it's hidden property. Making something hidden is no guarantee it won't be seen or printed (even if not seen), as those settings depend on how the end user has Word configured.

Comment: Actually, after clicking a submit button at the end of the document all the hidden text is deleted. I chose to hide it only during editing in order to make it reversible. I didn't understand what you said about not being in range.

Comment: Your 'Selection.Range' references do not insert content *into* a bookmark; at best they'll insert it after or in place of whatever is selected. If what is selected is a bookmark, the content will be inserted *after* it.

Comment: The 'selection.range' was put only to give the button two states. By clicking the button it gets selected and replaced with the other button from autotext. The bookmark that I want to be switched from hidden status is placed after the selection. For testing purposes I left only `Expand1` Macrobutton with one line of VBA: `Bookmarks("CollapseMentiuniReclamant").Range.Font.Hidden = False` and it's still not showing.

Comment: In your document, press F5 (Goto) and choose the CollapseMentiuniReclamant bookmark. What gets selected?

Comment: The hidden text gets selected. In my case, it's only a word "list" that's positioned after all visible text.

Comment: The code 'Bookmarks("CollapseMentiuniReclamant").Range.Font.Hidden = False' and your Expand1 macro both work for me - including when the latter is triggered by a MACROBUTTON field. Check your field coding.

Comment: The button works because I've added a MsgBox and the message pops out. I'll try today on a different computer. Thank you!

Comment: the code worked after I've added `ActiveDocument.` before  `'Bookmarks("CollapseMentiuniReclamant").Range.Font.Hidden = False'`. I can't seem to find a cause for this, because my code didn't trigger another document, all the computing was done using a single document.